# URL management issues in Yii

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

Hi I am having trouble in URl management in yii.

I have a Model Vendor and another Model Products. There is an action Info in both of the controllers. Now I want to create my URL as

www.example.com/abc.html instead of www.example.com/vendor/info/v-name/abc.html
www.example.com/xyz.html instead of www.example.com/product/info/p-name/xyz.html

v-name and p-name are the parameters.

I have written the rewrite rule as

```
'<v-name:\w+>'=>'vendor/info',
'<p-name:\w+>'=>'product/info',
```

But that doesn't seem to work. As the first rule is applied in product case also and in the end the exception is thrown. What should be done?

Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: How does your `createUrl` call looks like?

Comment: my createUrl looks exactly how I want. Like www.example.com/abc.html the code is as Yii::app()->createUrl('vendor/info',  array('v-name'=>  $vendor_info->url_name));

Comment: Try add `'vendor\/<v-name:\w+>' => 'vendor/info'`, `'product\/<p-name:\w+>'= > 'product/info',`

Comment: I think this will be better done with .htaccess rules then Yii URL management

Comment: By adding vendor and product before the parameters works with the rule and no exception is thrown but the link changes to [link](www.example.com/vendor/abc.html) @Justinas

Comment: @JibranMusa yes, it's because when you come via direct link, system have no idea if it's `vendor` or `product` and apply first matching regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use a more generic rule:

`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/name/<name:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`

**name** attribute will be available in your actions:

`public function actionInfo() {
        $name = Yii::app()->request->getParam( 'name', 'defaultValue' );
    }`

Comment: there is no problem in getting the param value in action but the main problem I face is by writing a rule as if click the link of the vendor the first rule is applied the parameters are getting correctly but when I click the link of product then again first rule is applied and error occurs

Comment: From system's point of view, both URLs are identical
www.example.com/abc.html
www.example.com/xyz.html
because they match the same regexp (\w+), so it doesn't know, is it a product or a vendor.

Comment: yes exactly you are right. But isn't the parameter in, <v-name:\w+> and <p-name:\w+>, will be able to detect the difference for the system?

Comment: '<v-name:\w+>'=>'vendor/info' - this rule says literally the following: anything that matches \w+ regexp should be handled by the 'vendor/info' action and passes there v-name parameter containing everything that matches the regexp.

Comment: So, answering your question, no it doesn't differentiate it, it doesn't even searches for 'v-name' string, it creates a named parameter and passes it to the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your both links means `check if url contains word`. So `http://example.com/example` will have no information if it's product or vendor. Since your vendor rule stands above product so every url is matching first rule and not executing further. You need to add any "marker" to know if it's vendor or product.

```
'vendor\/<v-name:\w+>' => 'vendor/info',
'product\/<p-name:\w+>' => 'product/info',
```

but yes, your url will change. You can still change url to something like `<v-name:\w+>\/v` and url will look like `http://www.example.com/some name of your vendor here/v`